# How can I read all the $location services without using HTML5mode true?

Tags: angularjs

How can I config AngularJS to use $location but without any html5mode=true or any # in the URLs ?

Setting html5mode to false - makes $location.path to be empty
Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g0G1HTuAdZWJPf2FMUMT

And the Plunker's code is:

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <base href="/"/>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="SiteCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{title}}!</h1>
    <div >
      Site path: {{path}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

## script.js

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngRoute'])
.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
})

.controller('SiteCtrl', function($scope, $location) {

  $scope.title = "Bla";
  $scope.path = $location.path();

})
```

In the simplest way ..
Thanks in advance.